# ActiveRecord query on has_many :through in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

This is my **Organization Model:**

```
  class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users
      has_many :shipments, :through => :users
```

This is my **Shipment Model:**

```
  class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      validates :user_id, presence: true
```

I'm trying to access shipments **for all organizations but two**.

This code works but only returns shipments for the FIRST organization that's returned by my `.where.not` calls.  I would like to join the shipments for all Organizations returned by my `.where.not` calls.

```
Organization.where.not(name: "Admin Org").where.not(name: "Test Organization").first.shipments
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add your `User` model.

Answer (score 2):

We need to do the query on `Shipment` model to fetch all the shipments of all the organizations except those two, which we will filter out using `where.not` caluse.

So the query would be like this:

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:organization).where.not(organization: {name: "Admin Org"}).where.not(organization: {name: "Test Organization"})
```

And a bit cleaner:

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:organization).where.not(organization: {name: ["Admin Org", "Test Organization"]})
```

Comment: And please let me know if this works or not: `@shipments = Shipment.joins(:organization).where.not(organization: {name: ["Admin Org", "Test Organization"]})`

Comment: @DavidAldridge, thanks for the suggestion. I was not sure about the array, that's why wrote it in comment. Thanks for confirming me. :)

Comment: thanks much for the response!  Here's the error I get using this query.  I think it's because I don't have a direct association with Organization?

"Association named 'organization' was not found on Shipment; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Comment: @bnzelener, add `Shipment` model in your post.

Comment: @bnzelener, can you try this - `Shipment.includes(:organization).where.not(organization: {name: ["Admin Org", "Test Organization"]}).references(:organizations)`

Comment: Still getting the same error, but I've added the Shipment model.  Thanks!

Comment: @bnzelener, what is the output of Shipment.last.organization ?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'organization' for #<Shipment:0x007fa4ede57498>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75141/discussion-between-bnzelener-and-sharvy-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an array and using two .each blocks to dump shipments into it:

```
array = []
Organization.where.not(name: ["Admin Org", "Test Organization"]).each { |x| x.shipments.each { |z| array << z } }
```